# Splitting dataset properly

Tags: dataset

I want to split the dataset into Train (60%) Validation (20%) Test (20%), but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Concretely, should I try to achieve that ratio for the whole dataset, or on the per class level?

I expect that I should do that on the per class level, but that means that the rario won't be proper for the whole dataset?

What is the proper way to do it?